# How do I fix Google Translate API.V3 "Unavailable" error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translation-api

I'm using Google.Cloud.Translate.V3 2.0 in my ASP.NET-based web server backend. I just started getting this error from the release version on the server:

`Error translating string. Google returned: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="failed to connect to all addresses", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1618955760.803000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x86\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":3948,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1618955760.803000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x86\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\pick_first\pick_first.cc","file_line":394,"grpc_status":14}]}")`

It was working fine when I last used the service maybe a week or two ago. I don't get it when running debug on my development machine. I've rebooted the server and redeployed. Any idea what happened and how to fix it? The server is running Windows 8.1 Pro, the dev machine Windows 10. The Google Translate web page works fine on the server machine, so I have basic net connectivity.

Comment: It started working again today.  I didn't change any code, so I don't know why.  I'm leaving this open in case someone can shed some light on it.

Comment: Now it's doing it again.